# How can I get my Windows 7 serial key (when I have upgraded to Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, serial-number

Anyone know how I can get my Windows 7 serial key? I used to use Belarc advisor to see my Serial keys. When I use it on my newly upgraded Windows 10, it shows me a Windows 10 Professional serial key. Is this the same as my Windows 7 Professional key?

Comment: You can’t use that key anyway, because the license is in use as part of the upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Look at the COA on your device.  `Belarc Advisor` shows you the generic Windows 10 Professional key.  You were not assigned a unique key.  The key that is displayed cannot be used to install Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed on my Windows 8 installation that after upgrading to Windows 10, the Windows key was changed, upgraded to a new Windows 10 key in Belarc, but the Internet Explorer "key" still has the old Windows 8 key written next to it. I don't know if the same is true for Windows 7, but have a look at the Internet Explorer key, if it's different, it could be that it's the old Windows 7 key that wasn't changed during upgrade.

Comment: I tried looking at other PCs and the old Windows key does seem to be the same as the Internet Explorer key. I think this is the best lead, thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah. But after a clean install, old key disappears :(

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade has overwritten that previous data. If your key wasn't stored elsewhere (written down/saved) you will have to contact Microsoft. Though I don't guarantee they will be able to help if the Windows 7 install was OEM & never registered under your name.

Comment: The key stays the same but the meaning of the kwy swaps from win7 to win10. Microsoft states on their website that their support cannot recerse the process

Comment: Microsoft does not have our original license keys.  The author's Windows 7 key is written on the COA that exists on his device.  Microsoft cannot help provide that information.  Why are you suggesting this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to go back to your old operating system

Microsoft provides multiple cases in which you can reverse the key into your previous one:

- If it's been less than a month since you've upgraded to Windows 10, you'll be able to go back to your previous version of Windows from Settings > Update & security > Recovery.
- If your PC manufacturer provided the option, you might be able to restore your device to factory settings.
- If options to go back and restore factory settings aren’t available, you can use installation media and a product key to install a previous version of Windows.

Comment: That’s not true. For 30 days, you can revert to your old system, using the built-in option. That also reverts your license state.

Comment: [See this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/help-upgrade-windows-10) Look under "can i go back to my old operating system"

Answer (score -3):

Run `cmd` (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>->`cmd`) as admin. Type in:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

Comment: Please proof it

Comment: This only works on devices where there is firmware that contains a key, this displays NOTHING, on hardware that does not have that firmware.  Windows 7 devices would not have this firmware.  This answer isn't helpful to anyone running Windows 7 devices which is what the question was about.

Comment: Hey moron, the question is about getting the windows key WHEN the user has upgraded to Windows 10. Go back to your cave.